# Booting from 'USB: USB SanDisk ... ' failed; verify it contains a 64-bit UEFI OS

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, boot-loader, live-usb

I installed Debian on a USB drive using the regular install. When I tried booting from it it says on a black screen and won't let me go further:

> Booting from 'USB: USB SanDisk ... ' failed; verify it contains a 64-bit UEFI OS

I have 3 partitions on the USB:

- EFI
- /boot
- encrypted /